# Compatible Magento version installation

Tags: installation, version

I'm gonna start with a new Magento webshop project very soon. I've did some research on which modules I need to have / install to make the shop performance, experience and back-end a better fit. During my research I've came to the conclusion that many modules (free or payed) aren't compatible with the newest (stable) Magento version.

It made me realize I maybe need to install a lower Magento version. A version which is still stable but a bit more compatible with the most modules out there. I would like to get some advice / feedback on which version you guys prefer (maybe experienced) to install.

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest version of magento. Period.

In most cases, if you find some module that is at least 2 version behind current magento version, it has most likely been abandoned, and should not be considered a viable option.

The availability of modules should generally not dictate what version of magento to install, unless the module you need is business critical, and will only work in that specific version of magento. Which takes me back to the initial point of it being potentially abandoned, and you should get another/write a custom module in the latest magento version.